# Bitbucket Api is not working for me

Tags: api, bitbucket

This is the doc: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-restrictions-resource-387449181.html

I use this api:

```
GET https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo-slug}/branch-restrictions
```

And its response is null:

```
{"pagelen": 10, "values": [], "page": 1}
```

Comment: That's a valid response. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: But it shuld has some content ,In my repo,there are two branches:master and dev

Comment: You have two branches but not branches-restrictions...

Comment: well,How can i get the branches info

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments I understand that the *real* question is about getting the list of branches. The branches API is supported by version 1.0 while you're trying to access version 2.0:

```
https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/{username}/{repo-slug}/branches
```